# Service class is not a constructor TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

i don't have much experience doing backend development, and as of now, i haven't been able to solve this:
I get "TypeError: Service is not a constructor" when trying to instantiate a class

Service.js

```
const MockUtils = require('./mocks');
        class Service {
          constructor() {
            this.mockUtils = new MockUtils();
          }
        
          getUserRestrictions(userId) {
            return this.mockUtils.getUserRestrictions(userId);
          }
        }
    
    module.exports = Service;
```

controllers.js

```
const Service = require("../../Service")

const getRestrictions = (req, res) =>{
     const userRestrictions = new Service()
     userRestrictions.getUserRestrictions(req.params.id)
     res.send("get restrictions")
}

module.exports = { 
  getRestrictions
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: have you tried to console log what `service` is after you import it into `controller.js`?

Comment: Are you sure you're importing the right module?

Comment: @about14sheep im sorry, i didnt quite get what you mean, i have only one service that get methods from the one that parses the mock data

Comment: after you import it with `const Service = require("../../Service")`, run `console.log(Service)`. If its not the expected class signature you are probably importing the wrong module as @Bergi mentioned

Comment: @about14sheep i see, i got an empty object, however when i move the controllers in the file where the class module is, it does return the class name from the service, is it possible that i cannot import the class to another module?

Comment: When you get an empty object on a `require()`, that is usually a sign of a circular dependency where A requires B and B requires A or it can be more convoluted than that with A requiring B which requires C and C requires A.  When the nodejs CommonJS module loader encouters a circular dependency, it bails with `module.exports` as an empty object.

Comment: @jfriend00 thats exactly what i found out in the end